# Java 8 for use from IntelliJ on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, clojure, java-8

I want to install Java 8 in my Mac to be used from IntelliJ and Clojure. Is this the right install binary: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Comment: Yes that link is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The link is correct.**

You can also use [homebrew cask](http://caskroom.io/) to install Java 8:

```
brew cask install java
```

You can manage multiple java versions with [**jEnv**](https://github.com/gcuisinier/jenv) which is available on [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install jenv
```

(I nicked this from [this blog post by Andrew Jones](http://andrew-jones.com/blog/managing-multiple-versions-of-java-on-os-x/))